# OSQP is failing to build wheels

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install gamestonk terminal on a raspberry pi. And i am installing the poetry requirements using mini forge anaconda github but osqp is installed but trying to update from.0.6.2post0 to 0.6.2post5 and it fails. I get this entire error log for it. Can anyone help me out as to whats going on and how to fix it?

‘’’
Building wheel for osqp (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for osqp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [179 lines of output]
Disabling LONG
Remove long integers for numpy compatibility. See:
- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5906
- https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3823
You can reenable long integers by passing: --osqp --long argument.

```
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'src/extension/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp
  copying src/osqp/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp
  copying src/osqp/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp
  copying src/osqp/interface.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp
  copying src/osqp/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqppurepy
  copying src/osqppurepy/interface.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqppurepy
  copying src/osqppurepy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqppurepy
  copying src/osqppurepy/_osqp.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqppurepy
  package init file 'src/extension/include/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  package init file 'src/extension/src/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  package init file 'src/osqp/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/feasibility_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/basic_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/warm_start_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/codegen_matrices_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/primal_infeasibility_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/codegen_vectors_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/update_matrices_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/non_convex_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/polishing_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/derivative_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/mkl_pardiso_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/multithread_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/unconstrained_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  copying src/osqp/tests/dual_infeasibility_test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen
  copying src/osqp/codegen/code_generator.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen
  copying src/osqp/codegen/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen
  copying src/osqp/codegen/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  package init file 'src/osqp/codegen/files_to_generate/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/files_to_generate
  copying src/osqp/codegen/files_to_generate/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/files_to_generate
  package init file 'src/osqp/codegen/sources/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  package init file 'src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  package init file 'src/osqp/codegen/sources/configure/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  package init file 'src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running egg_info
  writing src/osqp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/osqp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/osqp.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/osqp.egg-info/top_level.txt
  listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
  reading manifest file 'src/osqp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'src/osqp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension/include
  copying src/extension/include/osqpinfopy.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension/include
  copying src/extension/include/osqpmodulemethods.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension/include
  copying src/extension/include/osqpobjectpy.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension/include
  copying src/extension/include/osqpresultspy.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension/include
  copying src/extension/include/osqputilspy.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension/include
  copying src/extension/include/osqpworkspacepy.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension/include
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension/src
  copying src/extension/src/.gitignore -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension/src
  copying src/extension/src/osqpmodule.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/extension/src
  copying src/osqp/codegen/.gitignore -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_basic_QP.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions      copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_feasibility_problem.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_polish_random.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_polish_simple.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_polish_unconstrained.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_solve.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_unconstrained_problem.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_A.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions      copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_A_allind.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_P.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions      copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_P_A_allind.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_P_A_indA.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_P_A_indP.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_P_A_indP_indA.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_P_allind.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_bounds.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions
  copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_l.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions      copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_q.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions      copying src/osqp/tests/solutions/test_update_u.npz -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/tests/solutions      copying src/osqp/codegen/files_to_generate/CMakeLists.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/files_to_generate
  copying src/osqp/codegen/files_to_generate/emosqpmodule.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/files_to_generate
  copying src/osqp/codegen/files_to_generate/example.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/files_to_generate
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/CMakeLists.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/auxil.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/constants.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/error.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/glob_opts.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/kkt.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/lin_alg.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/osqp.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/proj.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/qdldl.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/qdldl_interface.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/scaling.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/types.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/include/util.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/include
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/configure
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/configure/osqp_configure.h.in -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/configure
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/configure/qdldl_types.h.in -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/configure
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/CMakeLists.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/auxil.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/error.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/kkt.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/lin_alg.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src      copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/osqp.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/proj.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/qdldl.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/qdldl_interface.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src
  copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/scaling.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src      copying src/osqp/codegen/sources/src/util.c -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/osqp/codegen/sources/src
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/.local/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
      from cmake import cmake
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/gst/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/gst/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/gst/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 244, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 229, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 256, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 155, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z6tlsmv7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "setup.py", line 216, in build_extensions        File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/gst/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/gst/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for osqp
Building wheel for pmdarima (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [27 lines of output]
Partial import of pmdarima during the build process.
Requirements: ['joblib>=0.11', 'Cython>=0.29,!=0.29.18', 'numpy>=1.19.3', 'pandas>=0.19', 'scikit-learn>=0.22', 'scipy>=1.3.2', 'statsmodels>=0.11,!=0.12.0', 'urllib3', 'setuptools>=38.6.0,!=50.0.0']
Adding extra setuptools args
Setting up with numpy.distutils.core
/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/gst/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:739: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/pip-install-_g0zqggj/pmdarima_c2d288ff254244ceb11473e61eafe262/pmdarima/_build_utils/**init**.py", line 48, in _check_cython_version
import Cython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

```
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-_g0zqggj/pmdarima_c2d288ff254244ceb11473e61eafe262/setup.py", line 335, in <module>
      do_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-_g0zqggj/pmdarima_c2d288ff254244ceb11473e61eafe262/setup.py", line 331, in do_setup
      setup(**metadata)
    File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/gst/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-_g0zqggj/pmdarima_c2d288ff254244ceb11473e61eafe262/setup.py", line 175, in configuration
      _check_cython_version()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-_g0zqggj/pmdarima_c2d288ff254244ceb11473e61eafe262/pmdarima/_build_utils/__init__.py", line 51, in _check_cython_version
      raise ModuleNotFoundError(message)
  ModuleNotFoundError: Please install Cython with a version >= 0.28.5 in order to build a pmdarima distribution from source.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pmdarima
Running setup.py clean for pmdarima
Successfully built bt linearmodels
Failed to build osqp pmdarima
ERROR: Could not build wheels for osqp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects’’’